# C++ operator ++ and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I am taking my first steps in C++ having a good background in Java. I need to clear out some peculiarities of the ++ operator in C++. Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void __print(int x, int *px) {
 cout << "(x, *px) = (" << x << ", " << *px << ")" << endl;
}

int main() {
 int x = 99;
 int *px = &x;
 __print(x, px);
 x++; __print(x, px);
 x = x + 1; __print(x, px);
 *px = *px + 1; __print(x, px);
 *px++; __print(x, px);
 return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly to me, the program prints:

```
(x, *px) = (99, 99)
(x, *px) = (100, 100)
(x, *px) = (101, 101)
(x, *px) = (102, 102)
(x, *px) = (102, 134514848)
```

It seems that *px = *px + 1 does not have the same effect on *px as on x. But aren't these things the same??? Isn't it *px == x?

Comment: "It seems that *px = *px + 1 does not have the same effect on *px as on x." What makes you say that? I think you must have looked at the wrong line of the output.

Comment: FYI: Identifiers matching `^__\w*` and `^_[A-Z]\w*` are reserved to the implementation in any scope and those matching `^_[a-z]\w*` are reserved to the implementation in the global scope. TL;DR: don't use `__print`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The first one should be simply `__`. Identifiers with double underscores *anywhere*, not just the start, are reserved.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: right! Oh well...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the `*` operator works after the `++` so it returns the value of a wrong address. the operator precedence is important to know in c++. take a look at this :

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Add parentheses to change operator precedence, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void __print(int x, int *px) {
 cout << "(x, *px) = (" << x << ", " << *px << ")" << endl;
}

int main() {
 int x = 99;
 int *px = &x;
 __print(x, px);
 x++; __print(x, px);
 x = x + 1; __print(x, px);
 *px = *px + 1; __print(x, px);
 (*px)++; __print(x, px);
 return 0;
}
```

result:

```
(x, *px) = (99, 99)
(x, *px) = (100, 100)
(x, *px) = (101, 101)
(x, *px) = (102, 102)
(x, *px) = (103, 103)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with operator precedence. Try `(*px)++`;

Answer (score 0):

When you do `*px++` you actually add 1 to the address and then get the value. You most likely meant `(*px)++`.

Comment: No, the original value of the pointer is dereferenced before the increment occurs.

Answer (score 0):

*px + 1 takes the value that px points to and add it by 1

*px++ increments the address first and then takes the value px points to

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of precedence:

`*px = *px +1` reads as `(*px) = (*px) + 1`, and since px = &x, it is like `x=x+1`.

`*px++` reads as `*(px++)` hence you are actually moving the pointer forward and getting the value of what the memory holds as the next position respect to the x variable (most likely garbage).

Answer (score 0):

Precedence for ++ is more than *. Hence (px++) is calculated. Now *(px++) is a waste statement. You are neither assigning nor reading the value from the location. Moreover (px++) has a address of a location which may not have initialized. So you are getting the garbage value.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, so many people don't know how C++ operators work.  :)

Everyone is correct in pointing out it's a problem with the order of precedence, exactly what the problem is, however, seems to be eluding everyone.

*p++; as a statement does exactly one thing.  It increments the pointer.  After evaluating it and dereferencing its *original* value (which is then ignored in this case).

```
int  a[ 2 ] = { 10, 20 };
int* b = &a[ 0 ];
int  c = *b++;
```

In the above example, c will equal 10, and b will point to the second element of a (20).  Because the pointer `b` will be evaluated before the increment.